# How to display text between product thumbnail and CTA button on WooCommerce "Shop" page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce shop page displaying a series of books.

[image]

I'd like to add a line of text between the thumbnail and its corresponding 'View' button.

I thought this would do the trick:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'eyates_show_pub_date', 5 );

function eyates_show_pub_date() {
   echo '<p class="shop-badge">Publication Date:</p>';
}
```

Instead, it displays the the text below the 'View' button. I can't seem to find any other hooks that would be appropriate; nor can I find a template to add that to.

If anyone could shed some light on the matter for me, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: What happen if you use woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title?

Comment: oddly enough, it still shows up under the CTA button

Comment: You should better contact the theme author through its support threads, as nobody can realy guess and answer on something that is already customized by your theme or a plugin.